# Convert date from local timezone?

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, momentjs

The question is simple, I use momentjs to get the current date of the system, in particular this is the date returned:

```
Sun Jan 03 2016 17:17:00 GMT+0100 (ora solare Europa occidentale)
```

I want convert this date in this format like this:

```
03/01/2016 17:17:00
```

How I can achieve this?

This is my code:

```
moment(new Date()).toDate()
```

Comment: [Use the `.format()` function (Moment.js).](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use momentjs's [format()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) function to format the date.  As an example:

```
moment.locale('it');
moment(new Date()).format('dddd MM/DD/YYYY h:mm:ss');
```

This returns the date as `"Domenica 01/03/2016 10:17:49"`

Comment: Okay, and if I want display also the day name in my languages as italian?

Comment: Use `moment.locale()` to set the language.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Also, you can omit `new Date()` and just call `moment()` without parameters.  The current date and time is the default.